# Prevent phtml template from FPC/Varnish cache - Magento2.4

Tags: magento2.4, cache, full-page-cache, varnish

We created a custom phtml template with some customer specific php, that must be loaded for each customer/pageload again. So we created the phtml template and added the following code to `layout/default.xml`

The problem now is that this element is cached by block cache and FPC (Varnish). We do kno that it's possible to add the `cacheable="false`, but this prevents the entire page from being cached. And this custom template is loaded on each page, so then we disable the entire cache. How can we exclude this template from being cached?

Found also this tutorial, but we do need to display some php code instead of just a simple text line; https://aureatelabs.com/blog/how-to-use-private-content-or-sections-in-magento-2/

Code of default.xml in Magento_Theme:

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="country_switch_notice" template="Magento_Theme::html/switch_notice.phtml" before="-" />     
</referenceContainer>
```

Code of custom.phtml;

```
<?php
$locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY']);
?>
<?php if ($locale == "be"):?>

HTML CODE
    
<?php elseif ($locale == "uk"):?>

HTML CODE

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Can you share your PHTML file and also let me know which layout you are using? I'll check for more details.

Comment: @Msquare See my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **I have created a new custom section for updating content from the cache block. Please check the code below for more details.**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName**

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_section" xsi:type="string">VendorName\ModuleName\CustomerData\CustomSection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/CustomerData**

**CustomSection.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\CustomerData;

use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;

class CustomSection implements SectionSourceInterface
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function getSectionData()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::class)
                ->setTemplate("VendorName_ModuleName::custom.phtml")
                ->toHtml();
        return [
            'customdata' => $block,
        ];
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**sections.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="*">
        <section name="custom_section"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.file.cacheable" template="VendorName_ModuleName::custom_cacheble.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

**custom_cacheble.phtml**

```
<div class="custom-section-show" data-bind="scope: 'section'">
    <div data-bind="html: customsection().customdata"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "section": {
                        "component": "VendorName_ModuleName/js/section"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

**custom.phtml**

```
<?php
// $locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY']);
$locale = 'be';
?>
<?php if ($locale == "be"):?>

<h1>HTML CODE BE</h1>

<?php elseif ($locale == "uk"):?>

<h1>HTML CODE UK</h1>


<?php endif;?>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js**

**section.js**

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var sections = ['custom_section'];
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
            this.customsection = customerData.get('custom_section');
        }
    });
});
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: Works perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to fix this

Either use ajax to load your content for this block via controller

OR

use Private Content https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/cache/page/private-content/

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide an example to achieve this? Maybe using a custom module?